# $X$ a separable metric space with no isolated points. If $G \subset X$ is a countable dense $G_{\delta}$ subset of $X$, why is $X$ meager?

Tags: general-topology, baire-category

Let $X$ be a separable metric space with no isolated points.  Then if $G \subset X$ is a countable dense $G_{\delta}$ subset of $X$, why is $X$ meager?

I've written a couple things so far,

Let $G=\bigcap U_n$, where each $U_n$ is open in $X$ and $G$ is countable and dense.  It follows that each $U_n$ is dense in $X$.  Also, $G^c=\bigcup U_n^c$, a union of closed sets.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $G=\{x_n:n\in\Bbb N\}$, and for $n\in\Bbb N$ let $V_n=U_n\setminus\{x_n\}$; then each $V_n$ is still dense in $X$ (why?), and $\bigcap_{n\in\Bbb N}V_n=\varnothing$. Can you finish it from there?

Comment: Now we have $\bigcup V_n^c = X$, where each $V_n^c=\{x_n\} \cup U_n^c$, a closed set.  Also, $V_n^c$ is nowhere dense since if there were an open set inside of it then $V_n$ would intersect said open set, which is absurd.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: @user41728: You’ve got it. You’re welcome.